# Periodic piecewise sin-cos function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, piecewise

I need to get plot like this:
[image]

So I found quite similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5393205/condition-checking-when-using-numpy-piecewise-to-generate-a-piecewise-periodic-p) and have tried to adapt solution for myself:

```
def complex_abstract_generator():
    def Q1(t, f):
        return (np.sin(2 * np.pi *f*t) + np.cos(2 * np.pi *f*t))
    def Q2(t, f):
        return 2*np.cos(2 * np.pi *f*t)

    def Q_true(t, f, stat):
        period = 1 / f
        return (t % period < period / 2) == stat

    def Q(t, f):
        return np.piecewise(t, [Q_true(t, f, True), Q_true(t, f, False)], [Q1, Q2], f)

    t = np.linspace(0, 10, 150)
    f = 1/(1*np.pi)
    plt.plot(t, Q(t, f))
    plt.show()
```

But the result I got is:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**
I decided to change a code a little bit, so the result could look like that:
[image]

```
def complex_abstract_generator(time, delta):
    def Q_true(t):
        return ((np.sin(2 * t + np.pi)) >= 0) & (np.sin(2*t) < 0)
    def Q(t):
        return np.piecewise(t, [(np.sin(2*t) >= 0), Q_true(t), (np.sin(t) < 0)],
                            [ lambda x: np.sin(2*x) * 10, lambda x: np.sin(2*x ) * 5, lambda x: np.sin(8 * x + np.pi)])

    t = np.linspace(0, 18, 200)
    plt.plot(t, Q(t))
    plt.show()
```

Comment: Should the desired result be differentiable? The accepted solution is C0 continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your piecewise function is correct. I went on [Desmos online graphing calculator](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) and created a plot that matches what you're going for:
[image: Desmos graphing calculator image of piecewise function]

Then I used those formulas in the `numpy.piecewise` function:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Q(t):
    return np.piecewise(t, [np.sin(t/2)>0, np.sin(t/2)<=0], [lambda x:np.sin(3*x), lambda x:np.sin(x)*10])

t = np.linspace(0, 18, 150)
plt.plot(t, Q(t))
plt.show()
```

[image: Matplotlib graph of piecewise function]

That seems to match your intended plot.